# Print Microsoft project 2010 GANTT chart (scale issue)

Tags: microsoft-project, project-management

I am using MS project 2010. For some reason I cannot print my project according to my preferences.

I have about 60 activities. The project starts from 1 January to 30 June.

What I want is to print it on 2 A3 sheets which allows for bigger font size and less information per sheet.

Comment: Can your printer handle a3 paper?  Do you receive any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

copied from a [Microsoft Knowledge Base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/202164)

**Method 3: Scale the Entire Project**
If you want to scale the entire project (not just the timescale portion as in method 1), scale the entire project to fit the number of pages you want. To do this, follow these steps:

1. On the **File** menu, click **Page Setup**.
2. Click the **Page** tab.
   Choose the scaling option you want to use.
   Print your project.

**NOTE**: *When you scale your project for printing, the project information is scaled proportionally for height and width.*